# Safe limit of memory usage today?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing a game for iOS.  The memory I am using is around 80 MB according to the profile tool (no leaks).  That just seems like a lot of memory to me.  How much memory usage is safe, and are there any special programming issues associated with using a lot of memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about what devices you plan to get you game. iPads are just fine with 100 MB of ram games, iPhone 3G's don't even *have* 100 mb. If you use a lot of memory you app will be forced to close, this could cause major problems if the user is on an old device.

Comment: Probably iphones and ipod touches mainly.  I guess I'll have to figure ways to reduce my memory usage.  Most of the memory seems to get allocated during the menus preceeding the actual game itself and dealloc is definitely getting called.  I should be able to fix that and with it my memory concerns.  Thanks.

Comment: iPhone 3G has 128 mb of RAM :).  I guess you wanted to say they don't even have 100 MB for the user to use?

Comment: I just guessed with 100, but your answer is correct. The user won't have more than 100 mb available. In some cases *much* less.